# How can I temporarily disable transmission of an Ethernet device

Tags: linux, centos

I have an ethernet network with a few network cards attached and I want to make sure only one of them is transmitting during a configurable time interval (of the order of minutes). The objective is to maximize throughput and minimize latency for the transmitting interface.

Is it possible to temporarily disable and then re-enable the transmission side of the ethernet mac (without restart) ? This needs to be done in a programmable manner.

Comment: Could you add information on what you are trying to do/solve?

Comment: How are you planning to tell the NIC to become re-enabled? (This may affect the answer to your question)

Comment: This seems like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).  Have you done any testing to determine if there are any **actual** latency or throughput problems, or do you just think there might be?  If there is a problem, is it serious enough to warrant repeatedly disabling and re-enabling either or both NICs?   Have you considered using a single bonded interface with your multiple NICs instead of messing about with disabling & enabling them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a network interface to the "down" state, which means it will neither transmit nor receive. The direct command is

```
ip link set eth0 down
```

(where `eth0` is your interface name), and

```
ip link set eth0 up
```

But normally you want to run all the hooks and initializations, so you can use the legacy `ifup`/`ifdown` commands, and I wouldn't be surprised if systemd is its own way to do that as well.

Comment: I want to keep the reception side up.

Comment: You can't keep only the reception side up, because to actually receive any data, you'll have to transmit acknowledge packets etc. I'd also recommend to actually completely disable the interface and see how far it "maximizes throughput and minimizes latency" - you'll probably be surprised how little difference there is between just having no connections, and completely disabling the interface.

Comment: downing the interface will also be a source of race conditions where a packet is sent, then the interface is downed, so any ACK packet from the recipient just gets dropped, then when the host tries to re-send the un-ACKed packet there's no iface to send it on.   What the OP wants is a really bad idea.  For this reason and many others.